# How to Get the Row Index of a Kendo TreeList Custom createChild Command

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treelist

I have a Kendo TreeList that has the following custom commands:

```
{
    command: [
        {
            name: "Edit",
            imageClass: "fa fa-pencil"
        },
        {
            name: "Delete",
            imageClass: "fa fa-trash"
        },
        {
            name: "createChild",
            imageClass: "fa fa-plus"
        }
    ], title: "Actions", width: "300px"
}
```

I click the create child button, input my data and click "Update". This takes me to the "create" definition of my Kendo dataSource:

```
create: function (e) {//Called when the create child command is saved
    //Collect the data needed for the save
}
```

At this point I need to get the row index of the new row but I can't seem to find the right way to do that. I've tried things like:

```
$(e.target).closest("tr").parent().index()
```

But that gives -1

And:

```
var selectedRow = $scope.treelist.select();
var node = $scope.treelist.dataItem(selectedRow);
```

But node is undefined

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you have no reference of the row into the `create` event's scope. However, you can find the element inside the widget's DOM:

```
var index = $($("#grid").data("kendoTreeList").element).find(".k-grid-edit-row").index();
```

The active editing row receives the `k-grid-edit-row` class and you can easily find it inside the widget's DOM tree.

[Working Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OJawA).

Not sure if is this what you really want.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I need. Thank you.